# Ensuring consistency between solr and oracle database

Tags: java, design, architecture

I have a java program, I want to insert data into oracle db and solr at the same time. How can I make sure that data in the db and solr are consistent?

Comment: You could make them eventually consistent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966489/can-one-make-apache-solr-index-transactionally-consistent-with-db-being-indexed

Answer (score 1):

Knowing nothing about Solr, I'll *assume* it's non-transactional.

In that case, start a transaction in Oracle database and make changes.  Then make the matching changes in Solr.  If the Solr changes succeed, commit the Oracle transaction; if not, roll it back.

It's not perfect by any means but you're using the transactional strength of one element to make up for the deficiencies of the other.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to update one in a transaction and, while the transaction is still active, update the other.  If both succeed then commit the transaction.  If either the first or second fail, roll back the transaction.